# NVM version issue between different Terminals on Mac

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I was using node version 12.18.0 and wanted to change it to 13.7.0 and used the following command in the iterm2 terminal in a directory to update my node version to 13.7.0 `nvm install 13.7.0 --reinstall-packages from=12.18.0` and once it was done, entered the `node -v` command to check the version and it was shown as 13.7.0

I opened another terminal after this under the same directory and entered the `node -v` and 12.18.0 was shown as the current node version. did i upgrade my node version correctly? I am entering nvm use 13.7.0 whenever I open a new terminal in VS code under the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you did it correctly. You should run `nvm alias default 13.7.0` to use the newly installed version by default

Comment: I did make the new version default by using the alias, but again in the new terminal when checking the version using node -v, it is showing the older version.